# binary excess notation

Tags: binary, type-conversion, computer-science

i'm studying computer science and i can't figure something out of my own.

There is this number : `-233` using 10 bit representation

What i need to do is to represent with excess notation the number `(2^n-1)`

So, i came up with:

```
1 base 10 = 0000000001

2^10-1 = 1000000000
```

1 base 10 in my notation = 1000000001

So, my -256 is 0000000001

And my 255 is 1111111110

What is the -233 number following this notation?

The result on the book is `0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1`

My result: 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right path, but just did a small error.

As I was not familiar with the notation, I had to take a look at it first. It seems like K is usually chosen as 2^(n-1) = 2^9 = 512. Which means `00 0000 0000` = -512 and `11 1111 1111` = 511. I don't know how you get -256, maybe there is your error.

Now, from -512 (`00 0000 0000`) to -233 there is a difference of 279 (`01 0001 0111`). This seems to be the result of your example.

For easier construction you can do this (assuming K = 2^(n-1)) - example number -12:

- Use the binary representation of the positive value (12). `00 0000 1100`
- Add K (2^(n-1)): `10 0000 1100`
- Invert all bits: `01 1111 0011`
- Add 1 (because of the zero value): `01 1111 0100`